# VB.NET GUI choices

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

Can you point me to good non-Windows looking GUIs choices for VB.NET?  I'm needing free but with licenses that allow closed proprietary code.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean IDE or UI libraries/frameworks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175673/help-on-language-choice):

> I'll definitely want an attractive looking GUI. And nothing "Windows" looking.

Generally speaking, this is bad. Windows apps should look like windows apps. Otherwise hell will break loose:

[alt text http://forum.computerbild.de/attachments/pc-hardware/realtek-hd-audio-manager-front-panel-problem-1470d1205060406-r.jpg](http://forum.computerbild.de/attachments/pc-hardware/realtek-hd-audio-manager-front-panel-problem-1470d1205060406-r.jpg)

[alt text http://www.techfuels.com/attachments/applications/1262d1207391664-gigabyte-easytune-5-pro-gigabyte-easytune-5-pro.jpg](http://www.techfuels.com/attachments/applications/1262d1207391664-gigabyte-easytune-5-pro-gigabyte-easytune-5-pro.jpg)

Consider WPF to get a rich UI framework, though.

Comment: I'll never understand why hardware companies think we are bunch of muppets who wants to run a show called "pimp my computer"

Comment: @fm: Developers on embedded systems (and the management for companies that focus on that sort of thing) typically want this sort of interface. I'm dealing with that very issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for what it's worth, I'd advise against using custom-looking controls for the most part, since you're only confusing users (and thinking of several GUIs that use such a thing I can't really say they look more appealing and are easier or better to use).

If you can use .NET 3 or 3.5 you can use the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). By default it looks Windows-like but can very easily be styled to your needs (which is what WPF internally uses anyway for trying to look like Windows).

It has a very steep learning curve, however. But once you understood the basic concepts it's a very nice framework to work with and pretty easy to integrate custom looks for controls.

Comment: I'd agree that WPF is the way to go - the app will handle like a Windows app, but the interface generally looks more attractive. For example, Microsoft Expression Studio itself is written in WPF: http://www.softpedia.com/progScreenshots/Microsoft-Expression-Blend-Screenshot-58549.html

Comment: With the exception of Expression Web. Visual Studio 2010 is another example, though. I had the opportunity to work with WPF for the past year and it was a very pleasant experience.